# List of Figures/Tables - eliminate dots?

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

I need to eliminate the dots that appear in `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` results - is there an easy way to do that?

EDIT:

I think I need to actually eliminate the dots.  Modifying `@dotsep` via

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
...
```

does not appear to rectify the problem with revtex - I still get

```
! Illegal unit of measure (mu inserted)
```

for each figure, which ends up placing a whole bunch of `ptmu`'s where the dots would normally appear.

sample:

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb,11pt,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,hyperref,slashed,stmaryrd,bbold,eepic,pst-all,pstricks-add,multirow,listings}
\begin{document}
% with or without % \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000} % doesn't work
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
%...later, some figures and tables ala:
\section{a section}
\subsection{another section}
\begin{table}[t]
 \caption[ShortCaption]{BlahBlahBlahCaption}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
 some & data & here \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
 \label{tab_A}
\end{table}
\newpage
\section{yet another section}
\begin{figure}[t]
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a_png.png}
 \caption[Short]{Longer.}
 \label{fig_A}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The information about `revtex` was crutial. You should always clarify in your questions, at least, the document class used.

Comment: The `revtex4` class doesn't seem to support `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures`. Please post a *complete* minimal version of your code (simply add to the snippet you just posted `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and how you are producing the lists).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To suppress the leading dots from the LoF and LoT, you can redefine `\@dotsep`:

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb,11pt,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,slashed,stmaryrd,bbold,eepic,pst-all,pstricks-add,multirow,listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{10000}
\makeatother

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Subsection}
\begin{table}[!ht]
   \caption[Caption in LoT]{Caption in document}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
     some & data & here \\ 
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab_A}
\end{table}

\section{Another Test Section}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
   \caption[Short]{Long}
   \label{fig_A}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks:

1. As my example shows, the redefinition of `\@dotsep` produces the expected result. However, changing the order of the lists (using for example `\tableofcontents` *before* the other two lists) breaks the ToC; this strange behaviour could be the subject of a new question.
2. You are loading `pstricks`, which means that if you use `pstricks` code you can't compile your document directly with `pdflatex`; this implies that if you are actually going to use `pstricks` code, you will have to be really careful with the format of your figures (they will have to be in EPS format).
3. The class `revtex4` seems not to implement `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`, so it makes no much sense to use those command with this class. Using `revtex4-1`, the lists are supported and the solution redefining `\@dotsep` works as expected.

The strange behaviour of `\tableofcontents` was, in fact, a bug; I opened a question: [Problem with \tableofcontents in revtex4-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37385/3954) and **mforbes** provided a quick fix; here's the fix incorporated to your code:

```
\documentclass[aps,amsmath,amssymb,11pt,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,slashed,stmaryrd,bbold,eepic,pst-all,pstricks-add,multirow,listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{10000}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\let\toc@pre\relax
\let\toc@post\relax
\makeatother 

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{Test Subsection}
\begin{table}[!ht]
   \caption[Caption in LoT]{Caption in document}
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
     some & data & here \\ 
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \label{tab_A}
\end{table}

\section{Another Test Section}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
   \caption[Short]{Long}
   \label{fig_A}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: changing `@dotsep` does not seem to resolve the problem, and tocloft seems to not play nice with other packages - adding those to Q

Comment: @Carl: Please be a bit more specific as to why changing `\@dotsep` (note the presence of the backslash character, `\`) "does not seem to resolve the problem". E.g., do you get an error message? If so, what's the message?

Comment: @Carl: see my updated answer (the last paragraph).

Comment: messes up the ToC - section title collide with formatting; updating minimal example momentarily

Comment: @Carl: As I said in my updated answer, `revetex4` doesn't support `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`. Do you have to use `revtex4` or could you switch to the more modern `revtex4-1`?

Comment: ah, sorry - didn't edit that in; yes I did switch.  That lead to the ToC issue

Comment: @Carl: see my updated answer, paying special attention to the remarks. If the order of the lists in not acceptable, then you should answer a fresh new question (and consider this one as solved, accepting it).

Comment: eh, I'm resigned at the moment re list order.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Carl: now the issue with the order of the lists has been solved; see my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, you can compile `pstricks` with `pdflatex`. However, you need to include `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`, and is also good to use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. Also you will need to compile with the `--shell-escape` option (note that you should use only trusted packages with this option). Hence you should execute `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` (In windows you just need one hyphen `-shel-escape`).

Comment: wow, nice dedication on the ToC/LoF/LoT ordering issue.  Wish I could vote your answer up again!

Comment: @adn: yes, that's why I wrote "you can't compile[...] *directly*" ;-) It's really useful that you added the steps needed for the compilation; thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is a similar question to [Remove dots & Page numbers from TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55465/9075).

The "clean" solution is to use the package `tocloft` and

```
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
```

to finally remove the dots. In case you are using KOMA-Script, be aware that `tocloft` does not obey `\chapterheadstartvskip`.

Minium example: (does not work with revtex4-1 documentclass)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} 
\begin{document} 
\listoffigures
\listoftables 
\tableofcontents 
\begin{table}
My table
\caption{My table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55466/9075)

Comment: I really overlooked that the question was intented for revtex4-1 only. I updated my answer accordingly to support others falling in the same trap.