# Problem with \tableofcontents in revtex4-1

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

While I was answering [List of Figures/Tables - eliminate dots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37355/3954) I found some strange behaviour; this document:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\tableofcontents

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\section{Another Test Section}

\end{document}
```

produces the expected result:

[image]

but as soon as `\tableofcontents` is placed before the other two lists, as in

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\section{Another Test Section}

\end{document}
```

the resulting document shows some problems in the ToC; the section numbers and their titles overlap:

[image]

What is the cause of this problem and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that there is generic code for all toc-generating commands which expands to something like (see the definition of `\@starttoc` in `ltxutil.dtx`):

```
\toc@pre      % Loads previously saved \tocmax@section etc. and sets
              % \tocdim@section etc. to a fixes small value (5pt) 
...
\@input{\jobname.#1} % Formats the toc, lof etc. but only
                     % computes \tocdim@section etc. if the 
                     % .toc is loaded
...
\toc@post     % Saves \tocdim@section etc. as \tocmax@section in .aux
```

The `\tocdim@section` values are only computed properly in the actual table of contents (the lof and lot do not contain section lines).  If a lof of lot appears after the toc, then `\toc@pre` resets the values and `\toc@post` saves the reset values, which then get read and used next time.

The only way this code works properly as written is to make sure that the `\tableofcontents` command comes last.

### Quick Fix

Disable the resetting and writing of the various `\tocmax@*` information after the `\tableofcontents` is typeset:

```
\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\let\toc@pre\relax
\let\toc@post\relax
\makeatother 

\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Comment: I have reported this as a bug to the revtex developers.

Comment: Wow, great job answering this, been looking for weeks