# How to remove the dots in the tableof contents

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Figures/Tables - eliminate dots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/list-of-figures-tables-eliminate-dots)

I have created table of content in my thesis. How to remove the dots in each line?

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 12):

Simply use in the preamble

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you use a standard class you can manipulate the command `\@dotsep`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{200}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Of course with packages like `tocloft` there are other ways.