Matching the table of contents with the chapter style of quotchap package
I like to apply the quotchap package style of the chapter headings to the headings of the table of contents, and the list of figures. Due to using another package tocloft, I am getting a conflict.
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{report}

%% Removing the dots from ToC  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55830/114006
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} 


\usepackage{quotchap}

\title{ToC Style}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents      
\listoffigures   
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\end{document}


You need
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

Why did the author think to such a funnily named option to tell the package that it mustn't change the chapter titles? Who knows.
